# How to resolve LoadError: cannot load such file error in jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins

I am trying to run a ruby file from jenkins shell. 
I wrote following commands in jenkins shell-

```
cd /home/user/Desktop/Rubyfolder
ruby test.rb
```

But when i am running the build it is returning error:

```
+ cd /home/user/Desktop/Rubyfolder
+ ruby test.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- rest_client (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/user/Desktop/RubyScript/api_url.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It is returning success when i am running it from my system console.

**Please help. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Are you using RVM or Bundler?

Comment: Yes... i am using rvm @Kristján

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Jenkins isn't loading the RVM environment where your Gem is installed. Check out [RVM's instructions](https://rvm.io/integration/jenkins) on integrating it. There's also a [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RVM+Plugin) that might be helpful.

The summary steps are:

- Make sure RVM is installed for the `jenkins` user
- Run `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` from `jenkins` `.bashrc`
- Add `rvm use ruby_version[@gemset]` in your setup script

  - Or use `rvm rubyversion[@gemset] do <command>`